# how to hide a button depending on the selected file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I'm making a blog where I need a button to appear only if a user selects a specific story, if the user selects other reports, the button should not appear.

These reports are in markdown file.

I thought of using a conditional rendering with a state and use

```
{
 Show && (<div><div/>)
}
```

Here's the code where the commented part what was trying to do something

```
import markdownStyles from './markdown-styles.module.css'
import Show_button_1 from './show_button_1'


export default function PostBody({ content }) {

  /*const retornarPagina=()=>{
    if(content==_posts.receita_0.md){
      return  
           <Show_button_1/>
    }
*/
  return (
    <div className="max-w-2xl mx-auto">
      <div
        className={markdownStyles['markdown']}
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: content }}
      />
      <Show_button_1/>
    
    </div>
  )
}
```

I tried to do it this way but it didn't work (03/30/2022)

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import markdownStyles from './markdown-styles.module.css'
import Show_button_1 from './show_button_1'



export default function PostBody({ content }) {

  const [Show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const retornarPagina=()=>{
    if(content===_posts.receita_0.md){
      {setShow(true)} 
           
    }
  }



  return (
    <div className="max-w-2xl mx-auto">
     
      <div
        className={markdownStyles['markdown']}
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: content }}
      />
     {Show && (<Show_button_1/>)}
    
    </div>
  )
  

}
```

Comment: Why exactly is the `conditional` approach that you have suggested not working?

Comment: I couldn't apply

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understood the question correctly, but one crutch I used to conditionally render components was

```
{
   Show ? (<div><div/>) : (<></>) //doesn't render anything
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how to use this code

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

```
{content === '_posts.receita_0.md' && <Show_button_1/> }
```

If you need multiple lines:

```
{content === '_posts.receita_0.md' && ( 
    <Show_button_1/> 
)}
```

you won't be able to use conditional rendering on a full file, you may want to consider refactoring your code to send a title of the markdown file through props as well. so you would do something like so:

```
<MyComponent content={document.markdown} title={document.title}/>
```

Then you can easily do

```
{props.title === 'some_title' && <Show_button_1/> }
```

Comment: This code didn't work for me

Comment: can you explain what happened as a result?

Comment: There was no problem but the button did not appear

Comment: can you console.log your content props please. console.log(content)

Comment: the content itself appears

Comment: can you copy/paste the content of the console log in a comment below? paste the content that you wish to use on the button

Comment: Thats what you're returning in your props? @Mpimenta if that's the case then you won't be able to do what you're asking.

Comment: The console.log content is that of other markdown files

Comment: <div className="flex flex-col lg:flex-row justify-center items-center lg:pl-4 lg:w-1/2">
                <a
                  className="mx-3 bg-black hover:bg-white hover:text-black border border-black text-white font-bold py-3 px-12 lg:px-8 duration-200 transition-colors mb-6 lg:mb-0"
                  >
                    Compre aqui 
                </a></div>

Comment: this is what the button contains

Comment: I need to know what you're receiving from your props. ({content})

Comment: when I put console.log(content) it receives what is inside another markdown file

Comment: See updated answer. @Mpimenta

Comment: this error is occurring: ReferenceError: MyComponent is not defined